# Counts of each bin in a distplot

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram

Is there any way to get the counts of each bin in sns.distplot? like for example,

```
sns.distplot(df.intervalL, kde=False, bins=[0,25,50,75,100], color='navy',rug=False, norm_hist=False)
```

I want to get the counts in each bin.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sns.distplot` returns the `ax` on which the plot has been created. The bars are accessible as rectangles in `ax.containers[0]`, for which you can investigate their height.

Note that in Seaborn 0.11, `sns.distplot` has been replaced by `sns.histplot`. (The code below still works with `sns.distplot` showing a warning that the function has been deprecated.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = np.random.randn(100, 10).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()
data -= data.min()
data  *= 100 / data.max()
bins = [0,25,50,75,100]
ax = sns.histplot(data, kde=False, bins=bins, color='navy')
for bar, b0, b1 in zip(ax.containers[0], bins[:-1], bins[1:]):
    print(f'{b0:3d} - {b1:3d}: {bar.get_height():4.0f}')
```

Output:

```
  0 -  25:   57
 25 -  50:  513
 50 -  75:  382
 75 - 100:   48
```

[image: example plot]

If you only want the values without the plot, you can also just call `counts, _ =  np.histogram(data, bins=bins)` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)).

Comment: yes. I wanted to get the counts values and plots as 3D bar chart.
Thank you very much!